# How I can authorize and upload video via GoogleAPIClientForREST for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I doing application for iOS with YouTube DATA API.
[Official google documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) have link to [this SDK](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client). But it is SDK dont work, because one of relationship "gtm-http-fetcher" for pod "gtm-oauth2" not found. More than that, ReadMe say:

> NOTE: This library has been replaced by Google APIs Client Library for
>   Objective-C For REST. New applications should use that instead;
>   existing application should be updated as soon as possible as the
>   Google servers will eventually stop accepting JSON-RPC requests.

Ok, I install next pods:

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Oauth2'
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper"
```

For example I try get list of my videos:

```
self.service = [GTLRYouTubeService new];
self.service.APIKey = @"API_KEY";

GTLRYouTubeQuery_ActivitiesList *query = [GTLRYouTubeQuery_ActivitiesList queryWithPart:@"contentDetails"];
query.mine = YES;

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"object is %@",object);
    NSLog(@"error is %@",error);
}];
```

and upload video:

```
self.service = [GTLRYouTubeService new];
self.service.APIKey = @"API_KEY";

GTLRYouTube_Activity *activObjec = [GTLRYouTube_Activity new];

GTLRYouTubeQuery_ActivitiesInsert *query = [GTLRYouTubeQuery_ActivitiesInsert queryWithObject:activObjec part:@"fileDetails"];

[self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"object is %@",object);
   NSLog(@"error is %@",error);
}];
```

And I get 401 error "Login Required" for upload video and 401 error "The request uses the `mine` parameter but is not properly authorized.".

Wherein I generate in google developer console API key for iOS (without bundle id) and OAuth 2.0 identifier:
[image]
[image]

and I add to info plist file:

```
<key>CLIENT_ID</key>
<string>client id from google console</string>
<key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
<string>reversed client id from google console</string>
<key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
<string>com.ncl.VideoImploder</string>
```

But I dont understand, that goes wrong. What I doing incorrect?

I see method:
- (void)setAuthorizer:(id )authorize;
in GTLRYouTubeService, but I dont understand send client_id and api_key to it method, I dont see similar properties in GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol protocol.

Please, say me, how setup authorization in GoogleAPIClientForREST?

Comment: can you provide me the code for uploading video on youtube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install following pod and use it to sign in:

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

After you sign in with `GIDSignIn` create `GTLRYouTubeService` instance:

```
let service = GTLRYouTubeService()
service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
```

All requests with `service` will be authorized

Comment: Don't work anymore. Property authentication don't have method fetcherAuthorizer() anymore.

Comment: @Argus import GTMSessionFetcher will resolve your problem